# How can i find out order wise topper in this month using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
name     amount  date
----------------------------------------------------
sarava   10000     2015-12-01
muthu    5000     2016-01-08
sarava   7000     2016-01-06
muthu    10000    2016-01-16
```

expected output height order taken on this month: 
`name->muthu

amount->15000`

Comment: `select * from table order by amount`?

Comment: This can be accomplished by a basic sql query. Please mention what all approaches you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try as below :

```
SELECT name, SUM( amount ),date_format( `date` , '%M' ) as month
FROM tablename
where month='January'
GROUP BY date_format( `created_at` , '%M' )
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to sum the amount by name. Maybe you want something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount, name from table1 GROUP BY name;
```